Using eslint, how to enforce one parameter per line in interfaces?
We do have @stylistic/object-curly-newline and @stylistic/object-property-newline to work with "curly objects", but they don't seem to work with interfaces.
Is there any other rule I can use to enforce that this is an error:
interface MyInterface {
  prop1: string; prop2: boolean;
}

But this is not?
interface MyInterface {
  prop1: string; 
  prop2: boolean;
}

